# Easy way to reprocess data for a scikit-learn.

Tags: python, scikit-learn, analytics, preprocessor

I have a data set that is under 1 million rows and 40 columns. All fields are categorical.  Some fields are true/false, and some have dozens of possible values.  These 39 columns are features. 1 true/false column is a label.   To use the appropriate lingo:  I would like to find a classifier that could be trained to predict the value of the Label. 
I wanted to try to run the file on sklearn..but I dint know how to transform ( reprocess?) my data to accepted by sklearn classifiers without help of professional programmer..
Is there a simple way out there?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample classifier for a 6-column and n-rows dataset

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('name_of_your_dataset.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, [2, 3, 4]].values 
# syntax : dataset.iloc[nrows, ncols].values
# ':' depicts all the rows in the dataset
# ncols takes 3rd, 4th and 5th column of the dataset into X
# Change that to your respective columns
y = dataset.iloc[:, 5].values

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)

# Feature Scaling
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
X_train = sc.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test = sc.transform(X_test)

# Fitting SVM to the Training set
# You can use any classifier to predict
# This is just a sample program
from sklearn.svm import SVC
classifier = SVC(kernel = 'linear', random_state = 0)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test set results
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Above is the code for

For Encoding Categorical Data, you need to create `dummy variables`.

Keep in mind that the `dummy variables` must be 1 less than the number of `categorical variables` in a column. Otherwise, the program might lead into a `dummy variable trap`

```
# Encoding categorical data
# Encoding the Independent Variable
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 0])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X).toarray()
```

This is the code for `encoding` categorical features of 1 column.Place this section of code just before `splitting of datasets`

You can do the same for other columns by changing the `0's` into your respective columns,
or by using a `for` loop

Comment: In the current version of sklearn (0.20) there is no need to `labelencode`  the strings before passing to OneHotEncoder. The new OneHotEncoder can handle them on its own.